# Custom button on maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps, button, google-maps-api-3, location

I am new to google api for android.

The issue is that I want a custom button in my google map activity that when pressed will show my current location that is already displayed on map.

I mean to say that if I am on another place on Google map, when I press that button it  moves the camera to my current location just like a default button in google maps activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first gain a reference to the GoogleMap object. This is done by implementing the OnMapReadyCallBack interface which allows you to gain access to the GoogleMap object. This is done as shown;

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    /* Extra code related to permissions and gaining access
       to location, etc.
     */

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

The part you are interested in is the last two lines.

```
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

The first line; enables/disables the location layer.

More information: While enabled and the location is available, the my-location layer continuously draws an indication of a user's current location and bearing, and displays UI controls that allow a user to interact with their location (for example, to enable or disable camera tracking of their location and bearing).

The second line is self explanatory (gets the Maps UI and enables the button you require).

For more info: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap

Answer (score 0):

mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
use this line in your code

Comment: What this will do?

Comment: this will enable your location and create a button on top right on your maps activity when ever you click on that button the map will show you current location.